# Как узнать срок окончания списка отозванных сертификатов(CRL)

Tags: python

меня интересует вышеуказанный вопрос. Сейчас пишу приложение на python, которое будет проверять в фоновом режиме истекли ли какие-либо сертификаты в указанной папке. Проверку сроков корневых сертификатов я смог реализовать, а вот как узнать сроки действия списка отозванных сертификатов не имею понятия. Конкретно интересует дата окончания действия сертификата, буду благодарен за помощь.

Comment: А какой формат (расширение) у сертификатов `.crt`?

Comment: навожу, кликаю правой кнопкой мыши, смотрю свойства, там написано "Тип файла: список отзыва сертификатов(.crl)"

Comment: По вашей теме кое-что есть: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44280747/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import openssl
crl = OpenSSL.crypto.load_crl(OpenSSL.crypto.FILETYPE_PEM, open('revoked.crl', 'rb').read())
crt = crl.to_cryptography()
print(crt.last_update) # Дата когда был создан/обновлен crl
print(crt.next_update) # Дата когда будет обновлен список отозванных сертификатов
```

Comment: А точно не `open('revoked.crl', 'rb').read()`?

Comment: В `load_crl` в случае если передан объект `str` будет переконвертирован в `bytes`. Но лучше явно указать `rb`.

Comment: Написал всё в точности, выдало вот такую ошибку:
Возникло исключение: OpenSSL.crypto.Error
[('PEM routines', 'get_name', 'no start line')]
  File "C:\Users\Руслан\Documents\Руслан\Проект сертификаты\CerSor\code.py", line 3, in <module>
    crl = OpenSSL.crypto.load_crl(OpenSSL.crypto.FILETYPE_PEM, open('15b548c6466ab827f8b11119c763b56fb5099a9e.crl', 'rb').read())

Comment: Скорее всего ваш crl файл в формате der. Вместо `OpenSSL.crypto.FILETYPE_PEM` попробуйте указать `OpenSSL.crypto.FILETYPE_ASN1`

Comment: Отлично, всё работает, благодарю вас от всей души)